# The percent decimal places attribute has no effect

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, number-formatting, lightswitch-2013

I am working on a HTML client, generated with LightSwitch. In Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, latest JavaScript Runtime.
In the ApplicationData I defined a table "tableA", with an attribute "savingsPercent" of the type "Percent". The configuration parameter "Percent Decimal Places" is set to 2 (by default).

When I use this attribute ("tableA.savingsPercent") in a screen, the showed value by the HTML client is 46.666666%. I expected 46.66%.

I could solve this by using "decimal" as an attribute type and then 
executing a postRender method containing this code:

```
$(element).text(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2) + "%");
```

but first I wanted to know if I am doing something wrong before I drop the percent-type as buggy.

Answer (score 0):

After I did some change to the database table, like changing the "tableA.savingsPercent" field from "required" to optional: the format in the HTML client showed the value with correct 2 decimal positions: 46.66%. This seemed to have triggered something more than just a clean and rebuild of the project.